# Why does Geocoding rearrange my points?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, geocoding

I am geocoding some addresses and it works just fine. However, all the points are rearranged afterwords. How can I stop it from rearranging the points? Is this a locator issue?

```
Geoprocessor GP = new Geoprocessor();
            GeocodeAddresses geocodeAddresses = new GeocodeAddresses();
            geocodeAddresses.in_table = workSpaceLocation + "\\" + addressTable;
            geocodeAddresses.address_locator = addressLocator;
            geocodeAddresses.in_address_fields = "Street Address;" +
               "City <None>;" + "State <None>;" +
               "ZIP <None>";
            geocodeAddresses.out_feature_class = workSpaceLocation + "\\" + outputFeatureClass;
            geocodeAddresses.out_relationship_type = "STATIC";

                IGeoProcessorResult result = GP.Execute(geocodeAddresses, null) as
                    IGeoProcessorResult;
                if (result != null)
                {
                    if (result.Status != esriJobStatus.esriJobSucceeded)
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed to Geocode.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to Geocode.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this by looking at the Locator Properties. There is a setting called "Presort input table by (fields)". This should not have any fields selected if you do not want your points to be rearranged.

[image: Locator Properties]